# Python Run a daemon sub-process & read stdout

Tags: python

I need to run a program and gather its output to stdout. This program (socat) needs to run in the background for the duration of the python script. Socat sits in dameon mode once it's run, but first it outputs some lines to stdout that I need for the rest of my script.

Command: `socat -d -d PTY: PTY:`

Output:

```
2011/03/23 21:12:35 socat[7476] N PTY is /dev/pts/1
2011/03/23 21:12:35 socat[7476] N PTY is /dev/pts/2
2011/03/23 21:12:35 socat[7476] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

...

I basically want to run that at the start of my program and leave it running till script termination, but I need to read the two /dev/pts/X names into python.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I came up with this which just hangs, I guess because it's blocking for the child process to terminate.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = 'socat -d -d PTY: PTY: &'

p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
output = p.stdout.read()

# Process the output 
print(output)
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT: Seems it may write to stderr, but the script still just hanges with and without the & even reading from stderr.

Comment: Does it work without the `&`?

Comment: Nope :( Sadly not, it just hangs.

Comment: Have you tried adding in a print statement to verify that it's blocking after your call to `Popen` and not blocking on the `read()` call?

Comment: Does socat produce a lot of output, or just a few lines?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import pty
import os

cmd = 'socat -d -d PTY: PTY:'

master, slave = pty.openpty()

p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=slave, stderr=slave, close_fds=True)
stdout = os.fdopen(master)
print stdout.readline()
print stdout.readline()
```

There are two problems with your version. Firstly, you call read without argument which means it will attempt to read everything. But since socat doesn't terminate, it never decides that it has read everything. By using readline, python only reads until it finds a newline. From my understanding of your problem that is what you need.

The second problem is that the C standard library will buffer outputs on pipes. We solve that by creating a pty with the openpty() function and passing it to both stdout and stderr of the subprocess. We use fdopen to make that file descriptor into a regular python object and we get rid of the buffering.

I don't know what you are doing with the socat, but I wonder whether it could replaced by using the pty module. You are copying one pty to another, and openpty is creating a pair of ptys. Perhaps you can use those directly?

Comment: Note that it's also possible to pass `stdin=slave`, but if you do that then anything that is passed in (you need to use `os.write(master, ...)` instead of `p.stdin.write(...); p.stdin.flush()` in that case) will be duplicated in the output, the same way how anything you type in the terminal get displayed -- unless noecho shell mode is set.

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess probably never closes stdout, so the `read()` call waits forever. To make matters worse, it will probably buffer its output when it figures out that it's a pipe instead of a console (the standard C library does this automatically, so this isn't a function of how cleverly written the app is). If so, probably the only option is to use an expect-style library such as [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).

Answer (score 0):

If you supply it with a pipe for stdout and stderr, I think the subprocess will block waiting for the pipes to be read. .read() should read to EOF, I think. Between them, those two issues prolly makes a deadlock.

However, I think that since .read() will read till EOF, it will block even if there is no stderr pipe.

You want to stick the reading in a thread, I think.