# C calling subprocess and injecting in stdin and reading it's stdout

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

I haven't found any satisfactory answer so excuse me if this has already been answered before.

Basically I'd like to be able to call a program and inject some data in its stdin and read it's stdout from within a C program.

I'd like to emulate this:

cat data.txt | program

where the output of program is captured and the data is written to stdin of said program.

It's a bit like this question but in C instead of python and I don't need the subprocess to live forever, just execute with input data, spit out the output and die.

[Repeatedly write to STDIN and read STDOUT of a Subprocess without closing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603334/repeatedly-write-to-stdin-and-read-stdout-of-a-subprocess-without-closing-it)

Comment: How do you start the subprocess?

Comment: I don't know, I was expecting that to be part of the answer (popen, fork, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popen() alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743771/popen-alternative)

Comment: The first answer contains an example of creating a subprocess with `popen()`/`exec…()` and using a pipe to communicate. As side note: Your Q sounds a bit if you have data in advance and want to get back data after the process finished. In such a case simply write the input data to a file, start the subprocess from that file and let him write out to a file and finally read the file after the process is done. Maybe this is easier in your scenario.

Comment: Of course, `fork()`, not `popen()`.