# python subprocess continuously feed stdin and read stdout which is possibly empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I am trying to write a python script that optimises the parameters of a compiled c script that I wrote. The program (`dups`) is taking an input (using `fgets`) and prints the input if it is not in the set of previously seen inputs.

My python script should continuously feed input to `dups` followed by an evaluation of it's output (which can be either the input or nothing).

I am using subprocess writing to its `stdin` and reading from its `stdout`. However, using various solutions, the script hangs after reading the first line.

The C program only writes to stdout and I know that it is flushing. Furthermore I am able to reproduce my error using a python script simulating `dups`.

Sample code:

Sample `dups` for easy reproduction:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
names = set()
while True:
    try:
        x = raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        print "Unexpected EOF, quitting"
        break
    if x not in names:
        print x
        sys.stdout.flush()
    names.add(x)
```

Main script:

```py
import subprocess
import pty, os #for solution 4

inputs = ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Mike']

solution = 4

arguments = ['./sample_script.py']

popen_nargs = dict(stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   universal_newlines=True,
                   )

if solution == 3:
    out_fname = "output.txt"
    f_w = open(out_fname,"wt")
    f_r = open(out_fname, "rt")
    popen_nargs['stdout'] = f_w
    popen_nargs['bufsize']=0

if solution == 4:
    master, slave = pty.openpty()
    popen_nargs['stdout'] = slave
    stdout_handle = os.fdopen(master)

child = subprocess.Popen(arguments, **popen_nargs)

for inpt in inputs:

    print "Testing '" + inpt + "'"
    child.stdin.write(inpt +" \n")
    child.stdin.flush()


    print "Result:"

    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running
    if solution == 0:
        for stdout_line in iter(child.stdout.readline, ""):
            print "-> '", stdout_line, "'"

    #http://blog.endpoint.com/2015/01/getting-realtime-output-using-python.html
    elif solution == 1:
        while True:
            output = child.stdout.readline()
            if output == '' and child.poll() is not None:
                break
            if output:
                print "-> '", output, "'"

    #https://gist.github.com/zhenyi2697/7229421
    elif solution == 2:
        output=''
        while True:
            result = child.poll()
            delta = child.stdout.read(1)

            if result is not None:
                print 'terminated'
                break

            if delta != ' ':
                output = output + delta
            else:
                if '%' in output:
                    print 'percentage is:'
                    print output

                elif '/s' in output:
                    print 'speed is:'
                    print output

                print "-> '", output, "'"
                output = ''

    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file
    elif solution == 3:
        f_w.flush()
        print "-> '", f_r.read(), "'"

    print "end iteration"

    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603334/repeatedly-write-to-stdin-and-read-stdout-of-a-subprocess-without-closing-it
    if solution == 4:
        print "-> '", stdout_handle.readline(), "'"

if solution == 3:
    f_w.close()
    f_r.close()

# Close the program
child.communicate()
```

Output:

- Solutions 0, 1 (don't terminate):

  ```
  Testing 'Alice'
  Result:
  -> ' Alice 
  '
  ```
- Solution 2 (doest terminate):

  ```
  Testing 'Alice'
  Result:
  -> ' Alice '
  ```
- Solution 3 (output.txt seems to be updated only in the end, despite bufsize=0):

  ```
  Testing 'Alice'
  Result:
  -> '  '
  end iteration
  Testing 'Alice'
  Result:
  -> '  '
  end iteration

  ...

  Testing 'Mike'
  Result:
  -> '  '
  end iteration
  ```
- Solution 4 (seems promising, but `read` and `readline` do not work when there is no output hence it does not terminate):

  ```
  Testing 'Alice'
  Result:
  -> ' Alice 
  '
  end iteration
  Testing 'Alice'
  Result:
  -> '
  ```

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), it says `Warning - Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.` So you should try something like `child = subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` and `child.communicate(your_input.encode())`