# How to access the parent process stdout from a subprocess in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, stdout

We have an exe that is run from Python (or we can run a Python file as a subprocess instead of an exe).

```
subprocess.run(["cmd.exe", "/c", {path to exe}, "<", {path to input}, ">", {path to output}]
```

Is there a way to access the stdout of the parent process from the subprocess? I cannot change the code that runs the subprocess. Also this is all running on a Windows server.

I have tried accessing the pid of the parent process but it seems like Windows doesn't have a process of accessing the stdout of a process from its pid. And printing to stdout from the subprocess redirects all outputs to the ported file due to the section of the command [">", {path to output}].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Run a daemon sub-process & read stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411780/python-run-a-daemon-sub-process-read-stdout)

Comment: matszwecja, Isn't that question about reading the output from a subprocess? I want to access the parent stdout from a sub-process (and I can't edit how to I run the subprocess I can't only change the code is the subprocess).